# PL/SQL construct to check for indeterminate value

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql, null

I am using following query to find difference in two dates in years and months in a PL/SQL procedure:-

```
  ...   
  years number;
  months number ;
  yrs_string varchar2;
  months_string varchar2;
  begin
  ...      
  select trunc(months_between(sysdate,date_of_birth)/12) into years,
  months_between(sysdate,date_of_birth) -  
  12*trunc(months_between(sysdate,date_of_birth)/12) into months from   
  tbl_student where student id = incoming_id;
  ---test 1
         if years = 0 then
            yrs_string := 'N/A or less than a yr";
         else
            yrs_string := years || 'years';
         end if;
   --- test 2
          if years = null then
              ....
```

However, in case date_of_birth is not entered in the table, test 1 and test 2
both fail. How to check for value of years or what PL/SQL returns in years if date_of_birth has not been entered by user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best approach would be to select the date of birth into a local variable, then do your tests on that:

```
...   
  l_dob date;
  years number;
  months number ;
  yrs_string varchar2;
  months_string varchar2;
  begin
  ...      
  select date_of_birth into l_dob
  from tbl_student 
  where student id = incoming_id;

  -- new test

  if l_dob is null then
       yrs_string := 'Date of birth is null';
  else
      years := trunc(months_between(sysdate, l_dob)/12);
      months := months_between(sysdate, l_dob) -  12*trunc(months_between(sysdate, l_dob)/12);
  ---test 1
         if years = 0 then
            yrs_string := 'N/A or less than a yr";
         else
            yrs_string := years || 'years';
         end if;
   --- test 2
          if years is null then
              ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful in Oracle working with null values.

The following condition is never true in Oracle:

```
if years = null then
```

You should use this one:

```
if years is null then
```

Consider the following cases:

```
if years = 0 then
  yrs_string := 'less than a yr';
elsif years is not null then
  yrs_string := years || 'years';
else 
  yrs_string := 'N/A'
end if;
```